# What are chip name macros are available in the HI-TECH C compiler?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, hi-tech-compiler

I am using the HI-TECH C compiler for the PIC16 Microcontroller, and I would like to conditionally compile different chunks of code depending on which specific microcontroller has been selected.

I know you can conditionally compile code with something like:

```
#if defined(MACRO1)  
    ... compile this code ... 
#elif defined(MACRO2) 
    ... compile this code ...
#endif
```

What I need to know is what pre-defined macros are available in the HI-TECH C compiler that will let me select on the specific microcontroller?

Comment: That depends on which toolchain you're using.

Comment: I am using HI Tech C compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page 98 of the HITEC C Manual lists all the pre-defined macros.

One of the entries is:

> _CHIPNAME
>   To indicate the specific chip type selected, e.g., _16F877

so you have, as other examples:

- _16F88
- _16F84A
- _16F505
- _16F777
- _16F1823
- ...

etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you asking about conditionally compiling code for different PICs using the defined name, you can use the predefined _CHIPNAME macro mentioned on page 106 of the 9.81  manual.
Or you can use the family (e.g _PIC12, _PIC14, _PIC14E as mentioned in the same table) or simply define your own.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want conditional assembly (or compilation) depending on the target chip, although your example is somewhat unclear.  I don't think you can put DEFINE in the target of a #IF as in your first case, and you appear to be testing for the same thing in both cases.

In any case, there is a symbol defined for the specific PIC model number as specified on the MPASMWIN command line or with the LIST directive.  The model-specific include files have a check in them to make sure the right model is selected to match the include file.  You can therefore write:

```
#ifdef __18f2520
     ;code here is only included when target is PIC 18F2520
  #endif
```

Comment: I think that's a typo.  If you read the _entire_ code snippet you'll see the second one is *defined(...)* which is perfectly valid.

Comment: And the "pic16macro" is a placeholder for the target of the question: "what should the OP be putting in there?"

Comment: @Majenko: The original question was very poorly written so that it was a bit confusing. I see Kevin has now fixed this, and added the very important information that HITECH C is being asked about. I am not familiar with that compiler, so I thought there might have been relevance to DEFINE in one place and DEFINED in another. You really don't expect two errors in a 4 line example specifically written to illustrate your question.  Couldn't the OP have bothered to proofread what he wrote!?